# Why S n' =? S n' simplifies to n' =? n' in Coq?

Tags: coq

I'm a beginner in Coq, and I've seen other examples when, if you have S n' on both sides of an equality, using the tactics `simpl` removes the successor function of both sides and simplifies them to n'.

Although it seems "obvious", I'm wondering why it happens with this specific function (successor). Is this behavior stated by any axiom or something like that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's because `_ =? _` is defined by structural recursion on both arguments.

```
Require Import Arith.
Locate "_ =? _".
(* Notation "x =? y" := (Nat.eqb x y) : nat_scope (default interpretation) *)
Print Nat.eqb.
(*
Nat.eqb = 
fix eqb (n m : nat) {struct n} : bool :=
  match n with
  | 0 => match m with
         | 0 => true
         | S _ => false
         end
  | S n' => match m with
            | 0 => false
            | S m' => eqb n' m'
            end
  end
     : nat -> nat -> bool
*)
```

When you use `simpl`, you're computing `_ =? _`, same as you're computing every other function that simplifies.

Note that there are two equalities for natural numbers: `_ = _` lives in `Prop` and checks whether two terms are exactly the same, "character for character", so to say. `_ =? _` is defined as above. They behave exactly the same [*], as the following theorem states:

```
Nat.eqb_eq: forall n m : nat, (n =? m) = true <-> n = m
```

However, they aren't defined in the same way (they don't even have the same type signature).

---

[*] This wasn't predetermined. You can define equivalence relations on types that don't behave like `_ = _`. For example, rational numbers can be represented as pairs of a natural number and a positive natural number. Thus, `<1,2>` can represent `1/2` and yet `<2,4>` also represents `1/2`. So we can define a relation on these pairs where `(1,2) =? (2,4) = true`, and yet `(1,2) <> (2,4)`.

Answer (score 0):

This would be due to the definition of `?=`. It does not happen for definitional equality.